# Including \DJ character into bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm writing a text and want to cite someone with a strike-through D in his family. Please see the MWE below:

*LaTeX file:*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwe}
\begin{document}
Foo Bar\cite{foo}
\end{document}
```

*BiBLaTeX*:

```
@Article{zbMATH00205607,
    Author = {Dragomir \v{Z}. {{\DJ}okovi\'c}},
    Title = {{Williamson matrices of order $4n$ for $n = 33, 35, 39$.}},
    Journal = {{Discrete Math.}},
    Volume = {115},
    Number = {1-3},
    Pages = {267--271},
    Year = {1993},
    Publisher = {Elsevier Science B.V. (North-Holland), Amsterdam}
}
```

When I try to compile the document, I'm getting the message `mwe.bbl:55: Paragraph ended before \name was complete.` The log file reads:

```
(./mwe.bbl
Runaway argument?
{{{hash=e95cf544cc8feefbc0a7a2390cb4acba}{{{{\DJ }}okovi\'{c}}}{{{\DJ \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \name was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.55 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

As far as I see it the braces are balanced. When I change the name to 'Dokovic' the document compiles and it seems correct. What can I do to insert the correct name?

Comment: Your document compiles without any complains, but it does not cite the article and has no `\printbibliography`. After adding that, it shows the strike-through `D` character in the bibliography correctly

Comment: The problem are the additional braces around the surname: type `Author = {Dragomir \v{Z}. {\DJ}okovi\'c},`

Comment: @egreg: I used the `.bib` file by the OP and there was no error message and the references showed up exactly like the screen shot in your answer. Hm, strange...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I got exactly the OP's error. What version of Biber are you running?

Comment: @egreg: `biber 1.8`, I believe newest version is `1.9`? Well, anyway, I have updated two weeks ago to TeXLive 2014, so I wonder why `biber` is installed with compilation date of 4th of November 2013.

Comment: Maybe the problem just shows with 1.9; but the input is wrong anyway.

Comment: @egreg: I just updated to 1.9 --> you are right, the error shows up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By typing

```
Author = {Dragomir \v{Z}. {{\DJ}okovi\'c}},
```

you're basically telling Biber that the author has a single letter family name and this confuses the parser.

The following works without problems (I used `filecontents*` just to make the example selfcontained).

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{zbMATH00205607,
    Author = {Dragomir \v{Z}. {\DJ}okovi\'c},
    Title = {Williamson matrices of order $4n$ for $n = 33, 35, 39$.},
    Journal = {Discrete Math.},
    Volume = {115},
    Number = {1-3},
    Pages = {267--271},
    Year = {1993},
    Publisher = {Elsevier Science B.V. (North-Holland), Amsterdam}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Foo Bar\cite{zbMATH00205607}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

You can avoid loading `inputenc`, but it's better if you do. I'd also avoid doubling braces in fields. The only field that can be affected by case change is the title. Just brace the words in titles that must keep the case of letters, such as names (the first word will never be changed).

[image]